# Validation Error messages of AngularJS are not showing in Ons-Dialog page in ONSEN-UI

Tags: angularjs, validation, cordova, onsen-ui

I am developing a Cordova Application using Onsen-UI. In one Page, I am showing one Dialog Box using ons-dialog which contains form elements. I have implemented validation using AngularJS directive ng-show.

Here after clicking the submit button, the Error messages are not showing in the dialog page, but validation is happening. Other pages of the application are showing all the error messages perfectly,but ons-dialog is not showing that error messages.

**My Code:**

```
<ons-template id="info.html">
<ons-dialog var="myDialog" animation="fade" cancelable>

    <ons-toolbar inline fixed-style>
        <div class="center">
            Info
        </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitted=true; myForm.$valid && myDialog.hide();" novalidate>

        <div style="text-align:center;margin:0px 10px 0px 10px">

            <input name="rFName" ng-model="rFName" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="" placeholder="First Name" required>
            <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
                <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rFName.$error.required">*required</span>

            </div>

            <input name="rLName" ng-model="rLName" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
                <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rLName.$error.required">*required</span>

            </div>

            <input type="email" name="rEmail" ng-model="rEmail" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="" placeholder="Email" required>
            <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
                <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rEmail.$error.required">*required</span>
                <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rEmail.$error.email">*Invalid email</span>
            </div>

            <input type="number" name="rPhone" ng-model="rPhone" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="" placeholder="Contact Number" required>
            <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
                <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rPhone.$error.required">*required</span>
                <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rPhone.$error.number">*Please enter valid phone number</span>
            </div>

        </div>


        <p></p>


        <div style="text-align:center" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <ons-button style="width:35%;background:#B54747" ng-click="submitted=true; myForm.$valid && myDialog.hide();">Save</ons-button>
            <ons-button id="cancel_btn" style="width:35%;background:#B54747" ng-click="myDialog.hide();">Cancel</ons-button>
        </div>

    </form>
    <p>

    </p>




</ons-dialog>
</ons-template>
```

Comment: please, provide also the controller code

Comment: Actually there is nothing interesting in the Controller Code. I've reverfied it.  Issue here is with the validation in Ons-Dialog element. Actually if we enter the correct details in page, Submit will hide the dialog performing validation. But if we dont enter the required details, Error messages of AngularJS is not showing. That is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just place ng-controller on form elements or form element's parent not just div tag which contains save and cancel button because form fields and form button are two different scope.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-submit="submitted=true; myForm.$valid && myDialog.hide();" novalidate>

    <div style="text-align:center;margin:0px 10px 0px 10px">

        <input name="rFName" ng-model="rFName" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="rFName" placeholder="First Name" required>
        <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
            <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rFName.$error.required">*required</span>

        </div>

        <input name="rLName" ng-model="rLName" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="" placeholder="Last Name" required>
        <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
            <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rLName.$error.required">*required</span>

        </div>

        <input type="email" name="rEmail" ng-model="rEmail" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="" placeholder="Email" required>
        <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
            <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rEmail.$error.required">*required</span>
            <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rEmail.$error.email">*Invalid email</span>
        </div>

        <input type="number" name="rPhone" ng-model="rPhone" class="text-input" style="width:100%;margin-top:10px" id="" placeholder="Contact Number" required>
        <div style="color:red;font-size:13px;text-align:center">
            <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rPhone.$error.required">*required</span>
            <span ng-show="submitted && myForm.rPhone.$error.number">*Please enter valid phone number</span>
        </div>

    </div>


    <p></p>


    <div style="text-align:center" >
        <ons-button style="width:35%;background:#B54747" ng-click="submitted=true; myForm.$valid && myDialog.hide();">Save</ons-button>
        <ons-button id="cancel_btn" style="width:35%;background:#B54747" ng-click="myDialog.hide();">Cancel</ons-button>
    </div>

</form>
```

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/5dt93ma8/)

Comment: Actually here Validation is happening,but error messages is not showing, That is the issue. Other pages are showing the correct output. But I think here is the issue with the Ons-Dialog element. See the above comment.

Comment: Could you please setup the jsfiddle to reprodue to your issue.

Comment: Actually I cant set up JSfiddle with the ONSEN-UI framework. I think it's problem with Ons-Dialog.